# Apple Air Play Cannot Connect

Tags: wireless-networking, appletv, airplay

## 1

My Macbook cannot connect to an Apple TV through Airplay.

I have set the Apple TV and the Macbook to the same Wifi Network, and I've set the proper settings on the Apple TV to connect everyone.

Here's the thing.

I have two user accounts on my Macbook and the other user is able to airplay ON THE SAME MACBOOK.

I've tried the whole keychain reset trick by putting the keychain folder on the desktop then restarting the computer without success.

I've reached out to Apple Support which have guided me all the way to reinstalling the OS.

Even with the OS reinstalled, it's still having the same issue.

How is this happening.

I'd give up if it wasnt working on both accounts yet I want to figure out why it only doesnt work on one user account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is one user account set up to use a full-tunnel VPN? Some VPN policies force **all** traffic through the tunnel and so strictly disallow local traffic that they break AirPlay. Cisco-based VPNs can do this, depending on how the VPN admin configured the policy.

Comment: None of the users are on VPN and are on the same network along with the AppleTV.